# How to Extract the Table from the HTML Code using Python BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the table from a HTML code using Python BeatifulSoup

```
{"html":"<table width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" class=\"gr_table_b1\">\n  <tbody>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\" class=\"gr_table_colm10\">Bond Type<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n         US Corporate Debentures\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Debt Type<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t Senior Unsecured Note\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Industry Group<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t  Industrial\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Industry Sub Group<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t Transportation\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\" class=\"gr_table_colm10\">Sub-Product Asset<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n         CORP\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Sub-Product Asset Type<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t Corporate Bond\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">State<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t  &mdash;\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Use of Proceeds<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t &mdash;\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Security Code<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t &mdash;\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n  <\/tbody>\n<\/table>\n<div class=\"gr_row_b6 gr_table_title\">Special Characteristics<\/div>\n<div class=\"gr_section_b1\">\n  <table width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" class=\"gr_table_b1\">\n   <tbody>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Medium Term Note<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t  N\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n   <\/tbody>\n  <\/table>\n <\/div>"}
```

And my desired outcome will be:

```
| Bond Type              | US Corporate Debentures  |
| Debt Type              | Senior Unsecured Note    |
| Industry Group         | Industrial               |
| Industry Sub Group     | Transportation           |
| Sub-Product Asset      | CORP                     |
| Sub-Product Asset Type | Corporate Bond           |
| State                  | —                        |
| Use of Proceeds        | —                        |
| Security Code          | —                        |
|                        |                          |
```

Comment: Could you add your desired output

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: updated desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have located / extracted the JSON, simply use `pandas.read_html()` to parse the table:

```
pd.read_html(json_data['html'])[0]
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
json_data = {"html":"<table width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" class=\"gr_table_b1\">\n  <tbody>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\" class=\"gr_table_colm10\">Bond Type<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n         US Corporate Debentures\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Debt Type<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t Senior Unsecured Note\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Industry Group<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t  Industrial\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Industry Sub Group<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t Transportation\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\" class=\"gr_table_colm10\">Sub-Product Asset<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n         CORP\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Sub-Product Asset Type<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t Corporate Bond\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">State<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t  &mdash;\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Use of Proceeds<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t &mdash;\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Security Code<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t &mdash;\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n  <\/tbody>\n<\/table>\n<div class=\"gr_row_b6 gr_table_title\">Special Characteristics<\/div>\n<div class=\"gr_section_b1\">\n  <table width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" class=\"gr_table_b1\">\n   <tbody>\n    <tr class=\"gr_table_row4\">\n      <td valign=\"top\">Medium Term Note<\/td>\n      <td valign=\"top\" align=\"right\">\n      \t  N\n      <\/td>\n    <\/tr>\n   <\/tbody>\n  <\/table>\n <\/div>"}

pd.read_html(json_data['html'])[0]
```

##### Output

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bond Type | US Corporate Debentures |
| 1 | Debt Type | Senior Unsecured Note |
| 2 | Industry Group | Industrial |
| 3 | Industry Sub Group | Transportation |
| 4 | Sub-Product Asset | CORP |
| 5 | Sub-Product Asset Type | Corporate Bond |
| 6 | State | — |
| 7 | Use of Proceeds | — |
| 8 | Security Code | — Special Characteristics Medium Term Note N |
| 9 | Medium Term Note | N |

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) library to print the formatted output.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

html_doc = """<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gr_table_b1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top" class="gr_table_colm10">Bond Type</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
         US Corporate Debentures
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top">Debt Type</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
         Senior Unsecured Note
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top">Industry Group</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
          Industrial
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top">Industry Sub Group</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
         Transportation
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top" class="gr_table_colm10">Sub-Product Asset</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
         CORP
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top">Sub-Product Asset Type</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
         Corporate Bond
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top">State</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
          &mdash;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top">Use of Proceeds</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
         &mdash;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top">Security Code</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
         &mdash;
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="gr_row_b6 gr_table_title">Special Characteristics</div>
<div class="gr_section_b1">
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gr_table_b1">
   <tbody>
    <tr class="gr_table_row4">
      <td valign="top">Medium Term Note</td>
      <td valign="top" align="right">
          N
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
values = []
for table in soup.find_all("table"):
    for row in table.find_all("tr"):
        values.append([])
        for column in row.find_all("td"):
            values[-1].append(column.text.strip())
print(tabulate(values))
```

```
----------------------  -----------------------
Bond Type               US Corporate Debentures
Debt Type               Senior Unsecured Note
Industry Group          Industrial
Industry Sub Group      Transportation
Sub-Product Asset       CORP
Sub-Product Asset Type  Corporate Bond
State                   —
Use of Proceeds         —
Security Code           —
Medium Term Note        N
----------------------  -----------------------
```